# malloc fails when asking for over 8 GiB

Tags: c++, memory

I am trying to load 1024 matrices into an OpenCV Mat. Each matrix is width*height=2200x2200 and each element is float, so it is about 19.36 MB for each matrix. I need to assign 1024 of these matrices which require over 19 GB of memory. This is okay as I have 128GB RAM in my virtual machine.

However, I have problem getting the code to run once I am over 443 matrices and the code produce segmentation fault.

I suspect that the gcc compiler is producing 32bit binary instead of 64bit, but it still failed with -m64 option to g++.

Could you have a look at my code and how can I load all these matrices at once?

```
int frame_num = 1;
int frames = 444;                   // max frames to process 
int hpixels = 2200;                 // number of roi horizontal pixels
int vpixels = 2200;                 // number of roi vertical pixels

unsigned int roi_size = vpixels * hpixels;  

float_t *roi = (float_t *)malloc(frames * vpixels * hpixels * sizeof(float_t));

Mat cv_source(vpixels, hpixels, CV_32FC1, roi + frame_num*roi_size); 

waitKey(0);

free(roi);

return 0;
```

Comment: [mre] is required. if you get a cv::Exception, **catch** and inspect it. -- retagging with `C++` (instead of C) because OpenCV usage implies C++. -- "443 matrices" is how much memory? I did your math for you, it's right on the boundary of 8 GiB. and why are you allocating your own memory? this is not an OpenCV issue if your code fails in the malloc. does it? where does it fail? details are required. please review [ask]

Comment: "I have problem getting the code to run" What do you mean by that? What is happening? It doesn't compile? You get segfault? What exactly is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with this expression:

`frames * vpixels * hpixels * sizeof(float_t)`

As all those variables are of type `int`, the result seems to overflow.

Try using types `size_t` for those variables.

Best regards.

Comment: I don't think that's true: `sizeof()` expression is of type `size_t` and thus all other integers get promoted to `size_t`.

Comment: @freakish nope; the first three multiplications only involve `int`s, so there are no promotions and the third one overflows (with 32 bit `int`); the fourth multiplication involves a `size_t` so the left operand is promoted, but it's too late — that value is already garbage.

Comment: I agree with this answer. I just ran the math. for `frames <= 443`, the entire expression stays positive. at 444, it flips into the negative. 8 GiB / 4 Byte = ~2 billion, int32 max.

Comment: Thank you very much and yes size_t resovled my problem! May I ask if I want to access a certain 2D matrix from the cv_source, what is the correct way to do so?

Comment: Maybe you can create a std::vector<cv::Mat> for working on a vector of images, instead of using only one